# Как правильно написать async function javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

Решаю задание и вот возникла проблема з написанием функции. Все методы прописал, а вот как задейсвовать их не знаю. Может кто-то помочь с реализацией.

> Создайте класс «Fighter» с такими свойствами, как name, health и power. Эти параметры должны быть установлены в конструкторе. Кроме того, класс «Fighter» должен содержать такие методы, как «setDamage», «hit» и «knockout».
>
> Метод setDamage имеет параметр «damage», и этот метод устанавливает повреждение бойца путем изменения значения health (health = health - damage) и состояния печатается в консоли.
>
> Метод «hit» имеет параметры «enemy», «point» и вызывает метод «enemy.setDamage (damage)». «Damage» вычисляется как `power * point`, где point является параметром от функции «fight», а power - это свойство бойца, наносящего урон.
>
> Метод «knockout» возвращает promise, который разрешается через полсекунды (используйте функцию setTimeout внутри обещания) и печатает в консоль сообщения «время закончилось» до того, как promise был разрешена.
>
> Создайте класс ImprovedFighter, который наследует методы и свойства класса Fighter.
>
> Для этого класса создайте метод «doubleHit», который вызывает метод наследования «hit» и передает там двойную point
>
> Для каждого класса создайте два экземпляра - fighter и Improfighter
>
> Создайте асинхронную функцию «fight» с такими параметрами, как fighter, improvedFighter и points.
>
> Функция "fight" должна начинать игру и может иметь различное количество параметров. Например, `fight(fighter, improvedFighter, 25, 13, 45)`, где `point = [25, 13, 45]`.
>
> Игроки ударяют друг друга один за другим с помощью метода «hit», который принимает point в качестве аргумента. Когда health достигает 0, печатается в консоль `that user in knockout` и вызывается метод «knockout». Вы должны подождать, пока promise не будет разрешен.

```
class Fighter {
  constructor(name, health, power) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = 100;
    this.power = power;
  }
  setDemage(damage) {
    this.health = this.healt - damage;
    console.log(this.health);
  }
  hit(enemy, point) {
    enemy.setDemage(this.power * point);
  }
  knockout() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout (() => {
      console.log("time is over");
      resolve();
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
}

class ImprovedFighter extends Fighter {
  doubleHit(){
    super.hit();
    enemy.setDemage(this.power * (point * 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: _doubleHit_ - неверно реализован, и опять опечатки в названиях полей и функций

Comment: Проблема с написанием какой функции?

Comment: @Grundy с функцией fighter

Comment: Есть ли описание того как должна работать функция `fight`, какие параметры принимать, что возвращать? То что сейчас в вопросе, либо не полно, либо не верное

Comment: @Grundy нет это все описание которое мне дали

Comment: Тогда текущее описание ошибочное, так как передается только один боец, если так и должно быть. то внутри функции просто цикл в котором бежать по массиву Point и вызывать у бойца `hit`

Comment: @Grundy должно как-то вызываться два бойца, подправил описание